# awk + match string after “=” separator

Tags: awk

I have a problem with the following awk syntax

```
echo " param1 param2 param3 = param1 AA , AB , AC , AD  "  | awk -F"=" '$2~/AA|AB|AC|AD/{print "passed"}'
```

The awk prints "passed", but it shouldn't be because after "=" I have "param1" and not "AA" or AB", etc.

The target of the awk is to print "passed" only if the string after "=" is AA OR AB OR AC OR AD.

and if I have something else after "=" then its not should print passed

how to fix the awk syntax?

lidia

Comment: don't open another similar thread to your previous ones.

Comment: sorry your answer isn't right , and I not get real answer so what I suppose to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need anchors:

```
awk -F= '$2 ~ /^(AA|AB|AC|AD)$/ {print "passed"}'
```

If you want to allow spaces:

```
awk -F= '$2 ~ /^ *(AA|AB|AC|AD) *$/ {print "passed"}'
```

Comment: echo " param1 param2 param3 = AA " | awk -F= '$2 ~ /^(AA|AB|AC|AD)$/ {print "passed"}'   , its not print passed why???

Comment: because you have spaces around AA. " AA" is not the same as "AA".

Comment: echo " param1 param2 param3 = AA   "  | awk -F= '$2 ~ /^ *(AA|AB|AC|AD)$/ {print "passed"}'  , its not work if I have space after AA , please what to do??

Comment: come on, don't be that helpless, do a little bit of work yourself!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo " param1 param2 param3 = param1 AA , AB , AC , AD  "  | 
awk -F"=" -v var="passed" '$2~/AA|AB|AC|AD/{printf "%s",var}'
```

Comment: its linux machine not windows